# How to find the unknown values of this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

Hi, our teacher gave this to solve but I am unbale as very less data is given. Anyone help. Thanks

[image]

I was able to solve the second part but the parallel part I cannot get it

---

[image]

Hi for those who were voting to close it down, I am so sorry, I am new to stack exchange I was able to do this part successfully, but the parallel circuit I was not able to solve it because I was not understanding what was happening to I1 and power 300 w

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework problem with no effort shown.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework attempt without a solution. Start by applying the theorems that you know, such as those relating power, voltage, current, and resistance, as well as KCL/KVL. If you get stuck, [edit] your question to show your work.

Comment: The two resistors are in parallel. You have the power and current, so determining voltage is easy. Then pick away at the other unknowns.

Comment: prajapati - Hi, FYI your new information has been moved from being an "answer" (since it wasn't a full answer to your question), to be an update of the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write a solution on a paper. The first task has infinitely many solutions, for definiteness,I assume R1=R2.
[image: write a solution on a paper]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. We don't give out answers to homework questions when the OP has done no work. See the comments below the question.

Comment: Oh, ok. Does EE.SE has some. rules/best practises that all user must know? I quickly looked for it on site, and didn't find something like rules. I understand why I shouldn't give answers to homework questions, but the first task looks really impractical and really has insufficient data.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot , but how did you get I1 = I2 =1.5 as we know in parallel circuits I total = I1+ I2+I3.....

Comment: In task 1(parallel circuit i get It=I1+I2. In task 2(serial circuit) i get It=I1=I2

Comment: If in first and second scheme the resistors have same value, then recalculate the values in the first task.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram shows two schematics. (The one on the right is open. It is has no circuit.) 
They are either a unified whole, or not. 
If they are a unified whole, then R1 on the right has the same value as R1 on the left, etc.  The schematic on the right can can be solved, and then the one on the right, but you end up with a different value for R1. 
That inconsistency tells you they are not linked. They are independent.
If they are independent, you do not have enough information to determine specific numerical values for the circuit on the left.